# What are the different origins of Saraswathi?

Tags: scripture, krishna, saraswati, radha, birth

It is well known from the scriptures that devathas use to manifest themselves from various origins. The origins may vary from kalpa to kalpa,  but there is always an inner meaning. For example, the birth of Ganapathi may vary from kalpa to kalpa but always takes origin from Siva and Parvathi.

I know the following manifestation of Saraswathi in which she manifested herself **from the lips of Radha**.

> Hear, O Muni! S'rî Krisna introduced first in this Bhârata, the
> worship of the Devî Sarasvatî, the holder of Vînâ in Her hands, under
> whose influence, the hearts of illiterate stupid persons become
> illumined with knowledge. **The amorous Devî Sarasvatî sprang from the
> end of the lips of Râdhâ** and so she desired to marry Krisna out of
> amorous feelings. S'ri Krisna, the controller of the hearts of all,
> knew it instantly and addressed the Mother of the people in true words
> proper to Her and beneficial to Her in the end.
>
> [[Chapter 4, 9, Srimad Devi Baghavatham]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk09ch04.htm)

Are there any other mentions of the birth of Saraswathi from the same or other scriptures?  Did she take birth from Radha every time?

Please present the episodes of some of the manifestations, if not sprung from Radha.

Comment: In Southern India, SriVaishnavas don't consider all the 18 puranas as equal. They are divided into satvik, rajasa and tamasik groups. Only the satvik puranasa like Padma purana, Vishnu purana etc are considered worthy of following. In those, devi Saraswati manifested from the 'manas' of Brahma dev only!

Comment: According to skanda purana only 10 shaiva puranas like shiva, linga, etc are considered worthy to be followed. As for devi Bhagwatam it's considered the most sacred in the 18 puranas in skanda purana and same is said for linga purana in narad puran. This part belongs to prakriti khanda book no 9 which is same as Brahma Vaivarta Purana. In different kalpas Mata Saraswati is created by different divinities like Lord Brahma, Lord Vishnu, Lord Rudra, Maa Durga, etc and in some kalpa she creates all.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Bhagawan Shiva creating Mata Saraswati.:**

**Sri Shiva Purana 7.2:2.31.:**

> *86. Sarasvatī born of the lotus-like speech of Maheśa is interested in worshipping Śiva and Śivā. May she grant my desire.*

**2. Maa Uma Tripura Sundari creating Mata Saraswati.:**

**Sri Brahmanda Purana.:**

> *A. From the left eye, which was of the nature of Soma (moon) came Brahma and Lakshmi.*
>
> *B. From the right eye, which was of the nature of Soorya (sun) came Vishnu and Parvati.*
>
> *C. From the third eye, which was of the nature of Agni (fire), came Rudra and Sarasvati.*

**3. Lord Brahma creating Mata Saraswati.:**

**Sri Shiva Purana 3.1.:**

> *31. O great sages, then another extremely wonderful Kalpa of Brahmā, named Viśvarūpa began to function.*
>
> *32. As Brahmā, desirous of sons, meditated on Śiva mentally, Sarasvatī (Goddess of speech) of great sound manifested herself. She was Viśvarūpā (Universe-formed).*
>
> *33. Īśāna of such renowned features, supreme lord of crystal-like pure brilliance and bedecked in all ornaments manifested himself.*

**4. Lord Vishnu creating Mata Saraswati.:**

**Mahabharata.:**

> *“Vyasa said, ‘On the occasion of the seventh creation, viz., that which was due to the primeval Lotus, Narayana, endued with the austerest penances, transcending both good and ill, and possessed of unrivalled splendour, at first created Brahma, from his navel
> ... The Supreme Lord, the god of gods, the chief of those endowed with intelligence (Viz Narayana), then began to think. The Goddess of Intelligence forthwith made her appearance before the puissant Narayana. Himself transcending all Yoga, Narayana then, by dint of Yoga, applied the Goddess of Intelligence properly. (MBH 12:349).*

**5. Mata Saraswati as the Creater, Preserver, Destroyer and Pranava.:**

**Shandilya Upanishad.:**

> *Sitting in the paḍma posture, the person should meditate that there is at the tip of his nose Gāyaṭrī, a girl of red complexion surrounded by the numberless rays of the image of the moon and mounted on a hamsa (swan) and having a mace in her hand. She is the visible symbol of the letter A. The letter U has as its visible symbol Sāviṭrī, a young woman of white colour having a disk in her hand and riding on a garuda (eagle). The letter M has as its visible symbol Sarasvaṭī, an aged woman of black/blue colour riding on a bull, having a trident in her hand.*

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..